# Converting definite integral from one form to another $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(2\csc(x))^{17}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to identify $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(2\csc(x))^{17}dx$$ equals which of the following definite integrals:

(A) $\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt2)}2(e^u+e^{-u})^{16}du$

(B) $\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt2)}2(e^u+e^{-u})^{17}du$

(C) $\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt2)}2(e^u-e^{-u})^{17}du$

(D) $\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt2)}2(e^u-e^{-u})^{16}du$. What is the correct way to approach these kinds of problems? (Don't use hyperbolic functions)

I was thinking of using some kind of substitution but couldn't identify a suitable one to convert from one form to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following substitution : $$\csc (x)= \frac{e^u+e^{-u}}{2}$$

---

The integral will convert to :

$$(A) \int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt2)}2(e^u+e^{-u})^{16}du$$